# Menu on Fullscreen Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, contextmenu

I have a fullscreen Activity launched by this way:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 setContentView(R.layout.preview);
```

I want to display a menu on the bottom of the screen, by this way:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
   return true;
}
```

with the uiOptions (AndroidManifest) `splitActionBarWhenNarrow`.
But nothing appears, what is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is because the "hardware" menu button is being phased out in favor of the ActionBar, see this [Android Developers blog posting](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) for more information.

Additional information on the ActionBar can be found at:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: Adding the legacy overflow button (3 dots) as default for ALL Android versions, if ActionBar is not used, would not hurt. I believe it is a stupid policy to force everyone to use ActionBar which occupies space. Menu was much better, as it could be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to inflate a *layout* as a *menu*

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
```

Perhaps it should be

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

Comment: The menu still not appears :S It seems to be because of the `requestWindowFeature` line. If I comment it, menu appears, but title too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to up the TargetSDK on an App that previously had worked fine. I had a full screen app where the user could draw on the entire screen and save from the options menu, but in trying to up the TargetSDK to bring new features to the device I found I lost this feature and all the internet advise was to implement an ActionBar.

After much thought I decided the best option was to implement my own menu from onBackPressed, and show the user a Handy Tip to alert the user of this somewhat odd behaviour when the Activity Was first launched. Obviously the menu needs to have an Exit option or exit the activity when back is pressed again.

It goes against standard Android behaviour, but my only choices were to put an unwanted ActionBar into my full screen activity and not make it full screen any more, or leave the app as a "legacy app" and put no new features in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in following line

```
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
```

change to

```
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

**Also make sure you have not saved

> menu.xml

under

> layout folder

.save it in menu folder.**

> Path will be res->menu->menu.xml